# Can you help me with my gulpfile.js ? I'm trying to make my Jade work

Tags: javascript, gulp, pug

Im really not sure what is the problem with this. When I us gulp jade command my terminal says :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
>       at Liftoff. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)

This is my gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const jade = require('gulp-jade');


// run this task by typing in gulp jade in CLI
gulp.task('jade', function() {
    return gulp.src('index.jade')
        .pipe(jade()) // pip to jade plugin
        .pipe(gulp.dest('index.html')); // tell gulp our output fo
});


gulp.task('styles', function() {
   gulp.src('stylesheets/style.sass')
       .pipe(sass())
       .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
            }))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
       .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['styles'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "."
        },
        open: false
    });

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function() {
   gulp.watch('stylesheets/style.sass', ['styles']);
});
```

Comment: have you just tried to clean node_modules folder and re install them by npm install command?